# How can I replace a match only at a certain position inside the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I have a function which has two params: string and match index to replace and i need to replace only match with that index. How can i do that?

**Example:**

```
replace('a_a_a_a_a', 1)
```

**Result:**

```
a__a_a_a
```

Comment: Try using regexp, look at this : [Replacing the nth instance of a regex match in javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183/replacing-the-nth-instance-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript

Comment: can you provide another example of input parameters so the required functionality is clearer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could look like:

```
var mystr = 'a_a_a_a_a';

function replaceIndex(string, at, repl) {
   return string.replace(/\S/g, function(match, i) {
        if( i === at ) return repl;

        return match;
    });
}

replaceIndex(mystr, 2, '_');
```

The above code makes usage of the fact, that `.replace()` can take a `funarg` (functional argument) as second parameter. That callback is passed in the current match of the matched regexp pattern and the *index* from that match (along with some others which we are not interested in here). Now that is all information we need to accomplish your desired result. We write a little function wish takes three arguments:

- the string to modify
- the index we wish to change
- the replacement character for that position

Comment: Close, but I think the `index` the OP is interested in is the `nth` occurrence of the pattern, not the string position of the match.

Answer (score 9):

For those like me who find regex to be cryptic, here is "pure JavaScript" way as well:

```
function CustomReplace(strData, strTextToReplace, strReplaceWith, replaceAt) {
    var index = strData.indexOf(strTextToReplace);
    for (var i = 1; i < replaceAt; i++)
        index = strData.indexOf(strTextToReplace, index + 1);
    if (index >= 0)
        return strData.substr(0, index) + strReplaceWith + strData.substr(index + strTextToReplace.length, strData.length);
    return strData;
}
```

Usage:

```
var mystr = 'a_a_a_a_a';
var newstr = CustomReplace(mystr, "_", "__", 2); //replace the second appearance
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/tXx5n/2/

Comment: Very nice. For another - slightly more brief solution - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10585234/3751385

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `match` returns an array, in case of multiple matches, so you could so something like this:

```
var string = "....";
var patt1 = /..../gi;
var results = string.match(patt1);
var newString = results.splice(i, i).join();
```

Instead of using a match, you could use `split` instead in your specific case:

```
var results = string.split("_");
var newString = results.splice(i, i).join("_");
```

It depends on how your input data can vary and where you need to do the split/match (that is why I did not specify any regex above, the split example is complete)...

Comment: Sorry, I added a bad example, i need to modify my match like that — before: im_1_2_3_4, after im_1_%2%_3_4. Function still the same, detect all numbers in string and replace match with my index.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex match with g flag 
var str="test string".match(/t/g)  output would be array of matched strings in this case "t"
[t,t,t]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [function parameter of the `replace` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), and also maintain an index (`i`) of matches.

```js
function replaceAt(string, replaceThis, replaceWith, at) {
  let i = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(at)) {
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => at.includes(i++) ? replaceWith : match)
  } else if (Number.isInteger(at)) {
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => i++ === at ? replaceWith : match)
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
// usage:
console.log(replaceAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", [2, 0])); // ".a.aaabcde"
console.log(replaceAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", 2)); // "aa.aabcde"

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(replaceThis, replaceWith, at) {
  let string = this, i = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(at)) { // e.g. console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceAt(/a/g, ".", 2)); => "aa.bcde"
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => at.includes(offset) ? replaceWith : match)
  } else if (Number.isInteger(at)) { //e.g. console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceAt(/a/g, ".", [2, 0])); => ".a.bcde"
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => offset === at ? replaceWith : match)
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
// usage:
console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceAt(/a/g, ".", [2, 0])); // ".a.aaabcde"
console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceAt(/a/g, ".", 2)); // "aa.aabcde"

function replaceExceptAt(string, replaceThis, replaceWith, at) {
  let i = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(at)) { // e.g. console.log(replaceExceptAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", 2); => "..a..bcde"
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => !at.includes(i++) ? replaceWith : match)
  } else if (Number.isInteger(at)) { //e.g. console.log(replaceExceptAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", [2, 0])); => "a.a..bcde"
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => i++ !== at ? replaceWith : match)
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
// usage:
console.log(replaceExceptAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", [2, 0])); // "a.a..bcde"
console.log(replaceExceptAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", 2)); // "..a..bcde"

String.prototype.replaceExceptAt = function(replaceThis, replaceWith, at) {
  let string = this, i = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(at)) { // e.g. console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceExceptAt(/a/g, ".", 2); => "..a..bcde"
    //return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => !at.includes(offset) ? replaceWith : match)
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => !at.includes(i++) ? replaceWith : match)
  } else if (Number.isInteger(at)) { //e.g. console.log(replaceAt("aaaaabcde", /a/g, ".", [2, 0])); => "a.a..bcde"
    return string.replace(replaceThis, (match, offset) => i++ !== at ? replaceWith : match)
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
// usage:
console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceExceptAt(/a/g, ".", [2, 0])); // "a.a..bcde"
console.log("aaaaabcde".replaceExceptAt(/a/g, ".", 2)); // "..a..bcde"
```