# Replace string using regular expression at specific position dynamically set

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regular expression to replace a string from the matching pattern string.

Here is my string :

```
"this is just a simple text. this is just a simple text. this is just a simple text. this is just a simple text. How are you man today. I Have been working on this."
```

Now, I have a situation that, I want to replace `"just a simple"` with say `"hello"`, but **only** in the **third occurrence** of a string. So can anyone guide me through this I will be very helpful. **But the twist comes here. The above string is dynamic.** The user can modify or change text.

So how can I check, if the user add `"this is just a simple text"` one or more times at the start or before the third occurrence of string which changes my string replacement position?

Sorry if I am unclear; But any guidance or help or any other methods will be helpful.

Comment: If possible , can clarify _"So how can I check, if the user add "this is just a simple text" one or more times at the start or before the third occurrence of string which changes my string replacement position?"_ ? What would be the "string replacement position" if "this is just a simple text" was added to the string ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:.*?(just a simple)){3}
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/yI6zG5/1)**

[image]

Comment: And can you do that in JavaScript ?

Comment: I get it that you didn't really test... Try and write the replace function with your regular expression...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with a dynamically built regular expression and a callback in which you count the occurrences of the searched pattern :

```
var s = "this is just a simple text. this is just a simple text. this is just a simple text. this is just a simple text. How are you man today. I Have been working on this.",
    pattern = "just a simple",
    escapedPattern = pattern.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'),
    i=0;
s = s.replace(new RegExp(escapedPattern,'g'), function(t){ return ++i===3 ? "hello" : t });
```

Note that I used [this related QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) to escape any "special" characters in the pattern.

Comment: Excellent, a LAMBDA callback expression!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(selector)
.data("r", ["simple text", 3, "hello"])
.text(function (i, o) {
    var r = $(this).data("r");
    return o.replace(new RegExp(r[0], "g"), function (m) {
        ++i;
        return (i === r[1]) ? r[2] : m
    })
}).data("r", []);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/2fm91qox/

See

[Find and replace nth occurrence of [bracketed] expression in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584748/find-and-replace-nth-occurrence-of-bracketed-expression-in-string)

[Replacing the nth instance of a regex match in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183/replacing-the-nth-instance-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

[JavaScript: how can I replace only Nth match in the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843441/javascript-how-can-i-replace-only-nth-match-in-the-string)