# Replace commas with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have strings (*`painting title, painter name`*) that have one or two commas, such as `Big House, Jone Doe` or `Big House, Blue, John Doe`. These are captions for the actual paintings. And I want to replace the correct comma with `by`.

I can get the captions with

```
const captions = document.querySelectorAll('#gallery .caption');
    for (const caption of captions) {
        var new_caption = caption.textContent.toString();
```

If I use `replace(","," by")`, that gets me the first comma. Then `replace(",/g", " by")` does it for both.  How do I replace just the second comma if there is one? Can't figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: valid regular expression would be `/,/g`

Comment: My typo. Sorry.

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: Expectations? just want to know how to replace the second comma, if there is one, with "by".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match at every second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589699/1260204). Use that in combination with replace.

Comment: Can you give us the value of `const captions` and what you want to have at the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace nth occurence of number in string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790263/replace-nth-occurence-of-number-in-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace only the **last** comma, you could use `/,(?=[^,]*$)/`, which looks for a comma and uses a lookahead assertion to ensure that it's only followed by text without a comma through the end of the string:

```js
const rex = /,(?=[^,]*$)/;
test("Big House, Jone Doe");
test("Big House, Blue, John Doe");
test("Big House, Blue, with Tree, John Doe");

function test(str) {
    console.log(str, "=>", str.replace(rex, " by"));
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For people who want to avoid regular expressions, you can define a `replaceAt` function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

Then, you can use [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find out the last appearance of comma:

```
const captions = document.querySelectorAll('#gallery .caption');
    for (const caption of captions) {
        let indexOfLastComma = caption.textContent.lastIndexOf(',');
        let newCaption = caption.textContent.replaceAt(indexOfLastComma, ' by');
        caption.textContent = newCaption;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string="We don't need no education, The Wall, Pink Floyd";
var lastComma=string.lastIndexOf(",");
if(lastComma!=-1)
  string=string.slice(0,lastComma)+" by"+string.slice(lastComma+1);
```

Or, in a function:

```
function replaceLastCommaWithBy(string) {
  var lastComma=string.lastIndexOf(",");
  if(lastComma!=-1)
    string=string.slice(0,lastComma)+" by"+string.slice(lastComma+1);
  return string;
}
```