# How to replace only specific matches in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

Let's say I have the following string:

```
Would you like some tea?
```

I want to replace only the second and third occurences of `o` with `0`, so it becomes:

```
Would y0u like s0me tea?
```

Or maybe I would like to replace first and last occurence, like so:

```
W0ould you like s0me tea?
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's not about *all* but *some*.

Comment: What is holding you back? If you *know* which letter you want to replace and which occurrence, then just *find* it, and do the job.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks but it doesn't. I want to know how to replace only some occurences, not all

Comment: @trincot Well I don't know which substrings should be replaced in advance. It could be 1st and 5th occurence of the word 'smart' or only the first occurence of the letter 'h'

Comment: So if you don't know which, then how should we? Is it random?

Comment: You can either use string functions to find your "o"s, and assemble the new string via cutting out substrings, etc. Or you use a regular expression to `replace`, with a callback function - if you keep a counter of how many times the callback function has been invoked, you can decide whether it should return the original `o`, or `0` instead ...

Comment: I ended up using the `String.replace`'s  replacer function to achieve this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790402/1673694

Comment: @JorensM please add an answer to this question?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yousha has provided a good answer, I have marked that as the accepted one. Edit: I decided to accept CBroe's answer instead as they answered sooner. Sorry Yousha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression and a callback function to replace:

```js
function replaceOccurences(text, search, replace, positions) {
  let regex = new RegExp(search, 'g')
  let counter = 0;
  return text.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return positions.includes(counter++) ? replace : search;
  })
}

console.log(
  replaceOccurences('foo bar baz foo djd foo sjsh', 'foo', 'XYZ', [1, 2])
);
```

If the found match is not at one of the given positions (starting to count at 0 here, as usual in programming), the `search` value will be returned as the "replacement" (so no change will actually happen), otherwise the `replace` value.

(Constructing the RegExp might need additional escaping, if the search term contains characters that have special meaning in regular expressions - that goes a bit beyond the scope of this question, so please do some additional research on that on your own.)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `replace()` method replaces only the **first** occurrence of a match. But you can use **regular expressions** and the `g` flag to replace all occurrences of a match:

```
let str = "Would you like some tea?";
let count = 0;

let replacedStr = str.replace(/o/g, function(match) {
  count++;
  if (count === 2 || count === 3) {
    return '0';
  }
  return match;
});

console.log(replacedStr); // Output is: "Would y0u like s0me tea?"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum speed use `String::indexOf()` to find matches and `String::slice()` to slice unchanged parts into an array. Then join by the replacer:

```
` Chrome/120
-------------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x  |  x1000000  134  139  141  143  147
CBroe       2.01x  |  x1000000  269  273  277  284  286
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
// @benchmark CBroe
{
function replaceOccurences(text, search, replace, positions) {
  let regex = new RegExp(search, 'g')
  let counter = 0;
  return text.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return positions.includes(counter++) ? replace : search;
  })
}
replaceOccurences('foo bar baz foo djd foo sjsh foo', 'foo', 'XYZ', [1, 2])
}

// @benchmark Alexander
{

function replaceOccurences(text, search, replace, positions) {
  let counter = 0;
  let parts = [];
  let idx, prevIdx = 0, prevCut = 0;
  while((idx = text.indexOf(search, prevIdx)) > -1){
    prevIdx = idx + search.length;
    if(positions.includes(counter++)){
      parts.push(text.slice(prevCut, idx));
      prevCut = prevIdx;
    }
  }
  prevCut < text.length && parts.push(text.slice(prevCut));
  return parts.join(replace);
}

  replaceOccurences('foo bar baz foo djd foo sjsh foo', 'foo', 'XYZ', [1, 2])
}

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```