# How to replace nth character of a string with another

Tags: string, swift

How could I replace *nth* character of a `String` with another one?

```
func replace(myString:String, index:Int, newCharac:Character) -> String {
    // Write correct code here
    return modifiedString
}
```

For example, `replace("House", 2, "r")` should be equal to `"Horse"`.

Comment: This is similar to this question. It has answer too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843441/javascript-how-can-i-replace-only-nth-match-in-the-string

Comment: @ShashiJeevanM.P.: Similar question, but different language: Swift is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Please see NateCook answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793735/1881472)

```
func replace(myString: String, _ index: Int, _ newChar: Character) -> String {
    var chars = Array(myString.characters)     // gets an array of characters
    chars[index] = newChar
    let modifiedString = String(chars)
    return modifiedString
}
```

**For Swift 5**

```
func replace(myString: String, _ index: Int, _ newChar: Character) -> String {
    var chars = Array(myString)     // gets an array of characters
    chars[index] = newChar
    let modifiedString = String(chars)
    return modifiedString
}

replace("House", 2, "r")
```

**This is no longer valid and deprecated.**

You can always use swift `String` with `NSString`.So you can call `NSString` function on swift `String`.
By old `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:` you can do like this

```
var st :String = "House"
let abc = st.bridgeToObjectiveC().stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(2,1), withString:"r") //Will give Horse
```

Comment: what is bridgeToObjectiveC()

Comment: This causes at least 1 copy (if not more), while the Swift team didn't allow the feature just to prevent that !! Anyone interested in copy-free version [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653964/8740349) (to only edit one node in the linked-list, which String internally could be, instead of copying)

Answer (score 38):

Solutions that use `NSString` methods will fail for any strings with multi-byte Unicode characters. Here are two Swift-native ways to approach the problem:

You can use the fact that a `String` is a sequence of `Character` to convert the string to an array, modify it, and convert the array back:

```
func replace(myString: String, _ index: Int, _ newChar: Character) -> String {
    var chars = Array(myString)     // gets an array of characters
    chars[index] = newChar
    let modifiedString = String(chars)
    return modifiedString
}

replace("House", 2, "r")
// Horse
```

Alternately, you can step through the string yourself:

```
func replace(myString: String, _ index: Int, _ newChar: Character) -> String {
    var modifiedString = String()
    for (i, char) in myString.characters.enumerate() {
        modifiedString += String((i == index) ? newChar : char)
    }
    return modifiedString
}
```

Since these stay entirely within Swift, they're both Unicode-safe:

```
replace("", 2, "")
//
```

Comment: String.characters() is deprecated in swift 4. Alternate ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz in Swift 4 you can change `var chars = Array(myString.characters)` to `var chars = Array(myString)` to fix the deprecation warning. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25921323/62

Comment: @LironYahdav Please add this in Answer. Thanks

Comment: This causes at least 1 copy (if not more), while the Swift team didn't allow the feature just to prevent that !! Anyone interested in copy-free version [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653964/8740349) (to only edit one node in the linked-list, which String internally could be, instead of copying)

Answer (score 23):

I've found this solution.

```
var string = "Cars"
let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
string.replaceSubrange(index...index, with: "t")
print(string)
// Cats
```

Answer (score 22):

In **Swift 4** it's much easier.

```
let newString = oldString.prefix(n) + char + oldString.dropFirst(n + 1)
```

This is an example:

```
let oldString = "Hello, playground"
let newString = oldString.prefix(4) + "0" + oldString.dropFirst(5)
```

where the result is

```
Hell0, playground
```

The type of `newString` is Substring. Both `prefix` and `dropFirst` return `Substring`. Substring is a slice of a string, in other words, substrings are fast because you don't need to allocate memory for the content of the string, but the same storage space as the original string is used.

Comment: How do you do the same for a `Substring`?

Comment: Exactly the same. You can replace the first line of the sample with `let oldString: Substring = "Hello, playground"` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For modify existing string:

```
    extension String {
        subscript(_ n: Int) -> Character {
            get {
                let idx = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: n)
                return self[idx]
            }
            set {
                let idx = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: n)
                self.replaceSubrange(idx...idx, with: [newValue])
            }
        }
    }

var s = "12345"
print(s[0]) 
s[0] = "9"
print(s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded upon Nate Cooks answer and transformed it into a string extension.

```
extension String {

    //Enables replacement of the character at a specified position within a string
    func replace(_ index: Int, _ newChar: Character) -> String {
        var chars = Array(characters)
        chars[index] = newChar
        let modifiedString = String(chars)
        return modifiedString
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let source = "House"
let result = source.replace(2,"r")
```

result is "Horse"

Answer (score 1):

I think what @Greg was trying to achieve with his extension is this:

```
mutating func replace(characterAt index: Int, with newChar: Character) {
    var chars = Array(characters)
    if index >= 0 && index < self.characters.count {
        chars[index] = newChar
        let modifiedString = String(chars)
        self = modifiedString
    } else {
        print("can't replace character, its' index out of range!")
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let source = "House"
source.replace(characterAt: 2, with: "r") //gives you "Horse"
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Swift Docs, I managed to make this function:

```
//Main function
func replace(myString:String, index:Int, newCharac:Character) -> String {
    //Looping through the characters in myString
    var i = 0
    for character in myString {
        //Checking to see if the index of the character is the one we're looking for
        if i == index {
            //Found it! Now instead of adding it, add newCharac!
            modifiedString += newCharac
        } else {
            modifiedString += character
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
    // Write correct code here
    return modifiedString
}
```

Please note that this is untested, but it should give you the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
func replace(myString:String, index:Int, newCharac:Character) -> String {

    var modifiedString = myString
    let range = Range<String.Index>(
        start: advance(myString.startIndex, index),
        end: advance(myString.startIndex, index + 1))
    modifiedString.replaceRange(range, with: "\(newCharac)")
    return modifiedString
}
```

I would prefer to pass a `String` than a `Character` though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to replace a single character:

```
var string = "This is the original string."
let offset = 27
let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
let range = index...index
print("ORIGINAL string: " + string)
string.replaceSubrange(range, with: "!")
print("UPDATED  string: " + string)

// ORIGINAL string: This is the original string.
// UPDATED  string: This is the original string!
```

This works with multi-character strings as well:

```
var string = "This is the original string."
let offset = 7
let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
let range = index...index
print("ORIGINAL string: " + string)
string.replaceSubrange(range, with: " NOT ")
print("UPDATED  string: " + string)

// ORIGINAL string: This is the original string.
// UPDATED  string: This is NOT the original string.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var s = "helloworld"
        let index = ((s.count) / 2) // index is 4
        let firstIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        let secondIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        s.replaceSubrange(firstIndex...secondIndex, with: "*")
        print("Replaced string is: \(s)") //OUTPUT IS: hell*world
```

This is working fine to replace string using the index.

Answer (score 0):

`String` class in Swift (till v5 and maybe later) is what other languages call a `StringBuilder` class, and for performance reasons, Swift does **NOT** provide setting character by index; If you don't care about performance a simple solution could be:

```swift
public static func replace(_ string: String, at index: Int, with value: String) {
    let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
    let end = string.index(start, offsetBy: 1)
    string.replaceSubrange(start..<end, with: value)
}
```

Or as an extension:

```swift
extension String {
    public func charAt(_ index: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)];
    }

    public mutating func setCharAt(_ index: Int, _ new: Character) {
        self.setCharAt(index, String(new))
    }

    public mutating func setCharAt(_ index: Int, _ new: String) {
        let i = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        self.replaceSubrange(i...i, with: new)
    }
}
```

> **Note** how above needs to call `index(...)` method to convert integer to actual-index!? It seems, Swift implements `String` like a linked-list, where `append(...)` is really fast, but even finding the index (without doing anything with it) is a **linear-time** operation (and gets slower based on concatenation count).

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public void createEncodedSentence() {

    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    int counter = 0;
    char a;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        a = sentence.charAt(i);

        if (a == '.') {
            buff.append('*');
        }
        if (a != ' ' && a != '.') {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            buff.append("");
        }
        buff.append(sentence.charAt(i));


    }

    encodedSentence = buff.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Replace Every Nth charater in String with another character*/

```
    func replaceAllNthChar(inputString:String, nthChar: Int, replaceBy:Character) -> String {
    var arrStr = Array(inputString)
    let n = nthChar
    
    for i in stride(from: (n - 1), to: arrStr.count - 1, by: n) {
        arrStr[i] = replaceBy
    }
    return String(arrStr)
}

print(replaceNthChar(inputString: "abcdefghijklmop", nthChar: 4, replaceBy: "_"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings in swift don't have an accessor to read or write a single character. There's an excellent [blog post](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/) by Ole Begemann describing how strings in swift work.

*Note: the implementation below is wrong, read addendum*

So the right way is by taking the left part of the string up to the `index -1` character, append the replacing character, then append the string from index + 1 up to the end:

```
func myReplace(myString:String, index:Int, newCharac:Character) -> String {
    var modifiedString: String

    let len = countElements(myString)

    if (index < len) && (index >= 0) {
        modifiedString = myString.substringToIndex(index) + newCharac + myString.substringFromIndex(index + 1)
    } else {
        modifiedString = myString
    }

    return modifiedString
}
```

Note: in my implementation I chose to return the original string if the index is not in a valid range

**Addendum** Thanks to @slazyk, who found out that my implementation is wrong (see comment), I am providing a new swift only version of the function.

```
func replace(myString:String, index:Int, newCharac:Character) -> String {
    var modifiedString: String

    if (index < 0) || (index >= countElements(myString)) {
        modifiedString = myString
    } else {
        var start = myString.startIndex
        var end = advance(start, index)

        modifiedString = myString[start ..< end]
        modifiedString += newCharac

        start = end.successor()
        end = myString.endIndex

        modifiedString += myString[start ... end]
    }

    return modifiedString
}
```

@codester's answer looks very good, and it's probably what I would use myself.
It would be interesting to know how performances compare though, using a fully swift solution and bridging to objective-c instead.

Comment: Actually, your code is wrong. And you can even find out why in the blog post you are referring to. The `substringToIndex` and `substringFromIndex` are `NSString` methods, and they use indices as defined for `NSString`, on the other hand you calculate `len` using `countElements`. You should either stick with `NSString`s indexing and length (`utf16count` in Swift) or `String`s. They do differ.

Comment: Ok my bad, I didn't check the source of what intellisense suggested me. Thanks for pointing that out, I appreciate it and I accept the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an efficient answer :

```
import Foundation
func replace(myString:String, index:Int, newCharac:Character) -> String {
return myString.substringToIndex(index-1) + newCharac + myString.substringFromIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: `substringToIndex()` and `substringFromIndex()` use NSString indexing, and thus aren't Unicode safe.

Comment: You're right, but I'm only dealing with alphabetic characters. I should have told it, however.