# Convert Swift string to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

How can I convert a String `"Hello"` to an Array `["H","e","l","l","o"]` in Swift?

In Objective-C I have used this:

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];
for (int i=0; i < [myString length]; i++) {
    NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [myString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [characters addObject:ichar];
}
```

Answer (score 461, accepted):

It is even easier in Swift:

```
let string : String = "Hello  "
let characters = Array(string)
println(characters)
// [H, e, l, l, o,  , , ,  , ]
```

This uses the facts that

- an `Array` can be created from a `SequenceType`, and
- `String` conforms to the `SequenceType` protocol, and its sequence generator
  enumerates the characters.

And since Swift strings have full support for Unicode, this works even with characters
outside of the "Basic Multilingual Plane" (such as ) and with extended grapheme
clusters (such as , which is actually composed of *two* Unicode scalars).

---

**Update: As of Swift 2,** `String` does no longer conform to
`SequenceType`, but the `characters` property provides a sequence of the
Unicode characters:

```
let string = "Hello  "
let characters = Array(string.characters)
print(characters)
```

This works in **Swift 3** as well.

---

**Update: As of Swift 4,** `String` is (again) a collection of its
`Character`s:

```
let string = "Hello  "
let characters = Array(string)
print(characters)
// ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "", "", " ", ""]
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why trying to join (`let joined = ", ".join(characters);`) the array results in an `'String' is not identical to 'Character'` error?

Comment: @Mohamad: Enumerating a string produces a sequence of characters, but `", ".join(...)` expects an array of strings. devxoul's answer below shows how you could split into an array of strings.

Comment: failed with emoji group: ``

Comment: @TomSawyer: Why do you think that is fails? Note that `` counts as a *single* Unicode grapheme cluster (and that is what `string.characters` represents), compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862282/swift-countelements-return-incorrect-value-when-count-flag-emoji/26863367#26863367.

Comment: This emoji is a group of few unicode character, if you separate them by characters will return wrong result.

Comment: `` is a sequence of four Regional_Indicator characters. According to the Unicode standard this is a *single* grapheme cluster.

Comment: @TomSawyer: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji if you want `` to be counted as two "characters" (even if it is a single Swift `Character` aka grapheme cluster).

Comment: I wonder what time/space complexity impact this has... is `characters` a copy of string basically? seems kind of lame having to copy the string into a different format just to be able to index the characters.

Comment: @Fonix: `characters` is a collection and a *view* on the strings characters. Creating an array from the characters makes a copy. – Of course can access the characters directly: `for i in string.characters.indices { print(string.characters[i]) }` or just `for c in string.characters { print(c) }`

Comment: @Fonix: ... On the other hand, random indexing into strings can be slow and it can be advantageous to create an array with all characters once. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371929/slow-swift-string-performance.

Comment: Argument or string does not confirm to expected type sequence

Comment: @zeeshanDar: What is your code? Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @zeeshanDar: Xcode 8.3.3. is Swift 3, so you have to use the Swift 2/3 version: `let characters = Array(string.characters)`

Comment: Oh. My bad. How do I upgrade?

Comment: @DaniSpringer: Swift 4 is currently in beta, you'll need Xcode 9 beta: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/.

Comment: @TomSawyer: Swift 4 (Xcode 9) implements Unicode 9, and now `Array("")` returns an array of two characters: `["", ""]`.

Comment: This creates [String.Element] type, which is not suitable for further operation

Comment: @ShrikantPhadke: Can you be more specific? Not suitable for which operation? It creates a `[Character]`, if you want a `[String]` then you'll find that e.g. in devxoul's answer.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting [String]. So below solution would be fine. let str1 = strHelloWorld.map { String($0) } or let str2 = strHelloWorld.map(String.init) or  var str3 : [String] = []
for s in strHelloWorld {
    strarr4.append(String(s))
}

Answer (score 136):

#### Edit (Swift 4)

In Swift 4, you don't have to use `characters` to use `map()`. Just do `map()` on String.

```
let letters = "ABC".map { String($0) }
print(letters) // ["A", "B", "C"]
print(type(of: letters)) // Array<String>
```

Or if you'd prefer shorter: `"ABC".map(String.init)` (2-bytes )

#### Edit (Swift 2 & Swift 3)

In Swift 2 and Swift 3, You can use `map()` function to `characters` property.

```
let letters = "ABC".characters.map { String($0) }
print(letters) // ["A", "B", "C"]
```

#### Original (Swift 1.x)

Accepted answer doesn't seem to be the best, because sequence-converted `String` is not a `String` sequence, but `Character`:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> Array("ABC")
$R0: [Character] = 3 values {
  [0] = "A"
  [1] = "B"
  [2] = "C"
}
```

This below works for me:

```
let str = "ABC"
let arr = map(str) { s -> String in String(s) }
```

Reference for a global function `map()` is here: http://swifter.natecook.com/func/map/

Comment: Slightly shorter: `arr = map(str) { String($0) }`

Comment: Use the `Array` initializer instead: `Array("ABC".characters)`

Comment: @chrisamanse, There's no difference between `"ABC".characters` and `Array("ABC".characters)`.

Comment: It's different in Swift 3. `"ABC".characters` returns a type `String.CharacterView`. To convert it to an array, specifically of type, `[Character]`, you'd have to use the `Array` initializer on it.

Comment: @chrisamanse Oh, I didn't know that. I was wrong. Thanks for pointing it out. By the way, I intended `[String]` instead of `[Character]` because op wanted a string array :)

Comment: It looks like you can no longer do that super swifty map(str) {} part...sadly

Comment: Very nice `"string".map(String.init)`

Answer (score 38):

There is also this useful function on String: *components(separatedBy: String)*

```
let string = "1;2;3"
let array = string.components(separatedBy: ";")
print(array) // returns ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Works well to deal with strings separated by a character like ";" or even "\n"

Answer (score 21):

For Swift version 5.3 its easy as:

```
let string = "Hello world"
let characters = Array(string)

print(characters)
```

*// ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]*

Answer (score 15):

**Updated for Swift 4**

Here are 3 ways.

```
//array of Characters
let charArr1 = [Character](myString)

//array of String.element
let charArr2 = Array(myString)

for char in myString {
  //char is of type Character
}
```

In some cases, what people really want is a way to convert a string into an array of little strings with 1 character length each. Here is a super efficient way to do that:

```
//array of String
var strArr = myString.map { String($0)}
```

**Swift 3**

Here are 3 ways.

```
let charArr1 = [Character](myString.characters)
let charArr2 = Array(myString.characters)
for char in myString.characters {
  //char is of type Character
}
```

In some cases, what people really want is a way to convert a string into an array of little strings with 1 character length each.  Here is a super efficient way to do that:

```
var strArr = myString.characters.map { String($0)}
```

Or you can add an extension to String.

```
extension String {
   func letterize() -> [Character] {
     return Array(self.characters)
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
let charArr = "Cat".letterize()
```

Answer (score 7):

for the function on String: `components(separatedBy: String)`

in Swift 5.1

have change to:

`string.split(separator: "/")`

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to do this is to `map` the variable and return each `Character` as a `String`:

```
let someText = "hello"

let array = someText.map({ String($0) }) // [String]
```

The output should be `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`.

Answer (score 4):

Martin R answer is the best approach, and as he said, because String conforms the SquenceType protocol, you can also enumerate a string, getting each character on each iteration.

```
let characters = "Hello"
var charactersArray: [Character] = []

for (index, character) in enumerate(characters) {
    //do something with the character at index
    charactersArray.append(character)
}

println(charactersArray)
```

Comment: Or just `for character in characters { charactersArray.append(character)}` without the `enumeration()`

Answer (score 3):

```
    let string = "hell0"
    let ar = Array(string.characters)
    print(ar)
```

Comment: There were no changes between Swift 2 and 3 with respect to this issue. This solution is identical to the Swift 2 version in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25921323/1187415.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, as `String` is a collection of `Character`, you need to use `map`

```
let array1 = Array("hello") // Array<Character>
let array2 = Array("hello").map({ "\($0)" }) // Array<String>
let array3 = "hello".map(String.init) // Array<String>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have four text fields `otpOneTxt`, `otpTwoTxt`, `otpThreeTxt`, `otpFourTxt` and a string `getOtp`.

```
let getup = "5642"
let array = self.getOtp.map({ String($0) })
                
otpOneTxt.text = array[0] //5
otpTwoTxt.text = array[1] //6
otpThreeTxt.text = array[2] //4
otpFourTxt.text = array[3] //2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an extension:

```
var strArray = "Hello, playground".Letterize()

extension String {
    func Letterize() -> [String] {
        return map(self) { String($0) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func letterize() -> [Character] {
    return Array(self.characters)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information why this will work? :)

Comment: @pix I think he meant for this to be a function defined in an extension of String.  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "cdcd"
let characterArr = str.reduce(into: [Character]()) { result, letter in
    result.append(letter)
}
print(characterArr)
//["c", "d", "c", "d"]
```