# How to store characters in string into an Array using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

Using Swift.  How do I take a String and separate each character into an array?

```
var someString = "123"
var someArray = []

someArray[0] = "1"
someArray[1] = "2"
someArray[2] = "3"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: Split a string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Swift string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array)

Comment: @MrCoder: The thread that you linked to is about splitting a string into separate *words* which are separated e.g. by a space.

Comment: @MartinR I saw your dupe straight after, but you can't highlight another 'dupe'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array` has constructor that takes `String` and produce array of characters.

```
let someString = "abcde"
let array = Array(someString)
```

Comment: More precisely, `Array` has a constructor that takes a `SequenceType`, and `String` happens to implement that protocol. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/25921323/1187415.

Answer (score 1):

yes there are many ways to achieve this task old and best way is to use for in loop in the following way

```
 var someString = "123"
    var someArray : Array<Character> = []

    for character in someString {
        someArray.append(character)
    }
    println(someArray)
```

Comment: I don't understand why I have been down voted the problem asked is easily solved through my code shared.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think you should explain your code. Your post currently appears in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue, so you might improve your post

Comment: @Pavi your post is indeed in `Low Quality Posts Review Queue`. Please provide some explanation.

Comment: Guys thanks for the reply in a hurry to give an answer or should I say to help the guy who posted it, I just went ahead with the code, will keep this in mind next time...