# Swift countElements() return incorrect value when count flag emoji

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, emoji, countelements

```
let str1 = ""
let str2 = "....."

println("\(countElements(str1)), \(countElements(str2))")
```

Result: 1, 10

But should not str1 have 5 elements?

The bug seems only occurred when I use the flag emoji.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I've tried different emojis and only flag emojis cause this. Even using different flags without a space causes this.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. "" is an "extended grapheme cluster" combined from REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER D and REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER E and counts as a single character, but "" should be 5 characters. Even "" gives a character count of one. Perhaps someone with a better knowledge of the Unicode standard can explain it.

Comment: It seems that an arbitrary sequence of "Regional indicator symbols letters" is treated as a single grapheme cluster. For example, `let str1 = "\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EB}"` prints as `` but counts as a single Character.

Comment: Interestingly, `str1.startIndex.successor() == str1.endIndex`

Comment: I cannot understand it, but here is [Grapheme Cluster Boundaries specifications](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)

Comment: @rintaro: Thanks for the link. I have added the [unicode] tag, perhaps that attracts some expert on that topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update for Swift 4 (Xcode 9)**

As of Swift 4 (tested with Xcode 9 beta) grapheme clusters break after every second regional indicator symbol, as mandated by the Unicode 9
standard:

```
let str1 = ""
print(str1.count) // 5
print(Array(str1)) // ["", "", "", "", ""]
```

Also `String` is a collection of its characters (again), so one can
obtain the character count with `str1.count`.

---

*(Old answer for Swift 3 and older:)*

From ["3 Grapheme Cluster Boundaries"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)
in the "Standard Annex #29 UNICODE TEXT SEGMENTATION": 
(emphasis added):

> A legacy grapheme cluster is defined as a base (such as A or カ)
>   followed by zero or more continuing characters. One way to think of
>   this is as a sequence of characters that form a “stack”.
>
> The base can be single characters, or be any sequence of Hangul Jamo
>   characters that form a Hangul Syllable, as defined by D133 in The
>   Unicode Standard, or be **any sequence of Regional_Indicator (RI) characters**. The RI characters are used in pairs to denote Emoji
>   national flag symbols corresponding to ISO country codes. Sequences of
>   more than two RI characters **should be separated by other characters**,
>   such as U+200B ZWSP.

(Thanks to @rintaro for the link).

A Swift Character represents an extended grapheme cluster, so it is (according
to this reference) correct that any sequence of regional indicator symbols
is counted as a single character.

You can separate the "flags" by a ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER:

```
let str1 = "\u{200C}"
print(str1.characters.count) // 2
```

or insert a ZERO WIDTH SPACE:

```
let str2 = "\u{200B}"
print(str2.characters.count) // 3
```

This solves also possible ambiguities, e.g. should "​​​"
be "​​" or "​" ?

See also [How to know if two emojis will be displayed as one emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji) about a possible method
to count the number of "composed characters" in a Swift string,
which would return `5` for your `let str1 = ""`.

Comment: Nice catch! Now it would be interesting to know _why_ they designed it that way, IMHO it's a wart.

Comment: Now, The question is... `countElements("" + "")` **should** be 1 , 2 or 3, in this semantics? :(

Comment: @rintaro: 1, because there's no delimiting character between the two flags in the result string.

Comment: @rintaro: Here is another example: `let a = "J\u{1F1EF}"; let b = "\u{1F1F5}P"`. Then `3 = countElements(a+b) < countElements(a) + countElements(b) = 2 + 2`. – My interpretation: `c = a + b` concatenates the Unicode scalar values of the strings, not the characters. Therefore `c` may have grapheme clusters which were not present in `a` or `b`.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but the end result is as DarkDust put it, it's a wart on Swift. Your app may receive a text string a user entered that contains adjoining Flag (or other double code point Unicode/Emoji) characters,  and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Randy, this is not Swift’s fault, as it correctly implements the Unicode standard. The problem the Unicode consortium faced was how to determine breaks between the regional indicators. There are three basic options: Seek to the first indicator and count every two (potentially slow); glue two indicators together with an invisible character; or split pairs of indicators with an invisible character. They ended up choosing option 3.

Comment: @MartinWinter But if I open a text document in TextEdit, type "", save, then hexdump it, I see that it does not insert a zero-width space. Similarly, I'm gathering tweets from Twitter's API and am not seeing zero-width spaces in between flags. Same if I send "" in Messages on OS X then check the SQLite database of sent messages. Is everyone just breaking the standard? I'm always stuck with option 1. Nothing seems to adhere to the standard.

Comment: @sudo Please note that the standard says “_should_ be separated by other characters”. In other words, nobody is breaking the standard by omitting such separators. In most cases, it is not necessary to do this anyway. It does however help with ambiguities. I do not have time to investigate this, but I seem to remember that the Cocoa text system has its own logic for determining character boundaries, i. e. separately from (or in addition to) NSString, and certainly from Swift String.

Comment: It's worth noting that as of Unicode 9.0.0 and [version 29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-29.html) of Unicode Standard Annex #29, the rules have changed. In a sequence of regional indicator symbols, grapheme clusters break after every second regional indicator symbol. I don't know whether Swift has implemented the new rules.

Comment: @user2357112: Apparently not, `print("".characters.count)` still prints `1` with Swift 3 (Xcode 8). But thanks a lot for the information, perhaps I'll file a bug report.

Comment: As @user2357112 mentioned, [rules GB12 and GB13](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#GB12) (new in revision 29) state that only sequences of two RI characters form a (legacy or extended) grapheme cluster. Oddly, this contradicts the paragraph quoted in the answer which is still part of revision 29. My guess is that the rules were changed without updating the text, so I submitted an error report to the Unicode consortium.

Comment: I'm mobile right now, but I wonder if Zero-Width Non-Joiner separates them into 2 characters

Comment: @Supuhstar: Indeed it does, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @user2357112: Apparently Swift 4 now implements the new rules (tested with Xcode 9 beta).

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I solved that problem, for **Swift 3**:

```
let str = "" //or whatever the string of emojis is
let range = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex
var length = 0
str.enumerateSubstrings(in: range, options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byComposedCharacterSequences) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
        length = length + 1
    }
print("Character Count: \(length)")
```

This fixes all the problems with character count and emojis, and is the simplest method I have found.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/39104563/1187415 (which I linked to in my answer) :)