# How to separate emojis entered (through default keyboard) on textfield

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I entered a two emojis in textfield ‍‍‍, here I'm getting total number of 5 characters length whereas 4 characters for first emoji and 1 character for second. Looks like apple has combined 4 emojis to form a one.

I'm looking for the **swift** code where I can separate each of emojis separately, suppose by taking the above example I should be getting 2 strings/character separately for each emoji.

Can any one help me to solve this, I've tried many things like regex separation or componentsSeparatedByString or characterSet. but unfortunately ended up with negative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update for Swift 4 (Xcode 9)**

As of Swift 4 (tested with Xcode 9 beta) a "Emoji ZWJ Sequence" is
treated as a single `Character` as mandated by the Unicode 9 standard:

```
let str = "‍‍‍"
print(str.count) // 2
print(Array(str)) //  ["‍‍‍", ""]
```

Also `String` is a collection of its characters (again), so we can 
call `str.count` to get the length, and `Array(str)` to get all
characters as an array.

---

*(Old answer for Swift 3 and earlier)*

This is only a partial answer which may help in this particular case.

"‍‍‍" is indeed a combination of four separate characters:

```
let str = "‍‍‍" //
print(Array(str.characters))

// Output: ["‍", "‍", "‍", "", ""]
```

which are glued together with U+200D (ZERO WIDTH JOINER):

```
for c in str.unicodeScalars {
    print(String(c.value, radix: 16))
}

/* Output:
1f468
200d
1f468
200d
1f467
200d
1f467
1f60d
*/
```

Enumerating the string with the `.ByComposedCharacterSequences`
options combines these characters correctly:

```
var chars : [String] = []
str.enumerateSubstringsInRange(str.characters.indices, options: .ByComposedCharacterSequences) {
    (substring, _, _, _) -> () in
    chars.append(substring!)
}
print(chars)

// Output: ["‍‍‍", ""]
```

But there are other cases where this does not work,
e.g. the "flags" which are a sequence of "Regional Indicator 
characters" (compare [Swift countElements() return incorrect value when count flag emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862282/swift-countelements-return-incorrect-value-when-count-flag-emoji)). With

```
let str = ""
```

the result of the above loop is

```
["", ""]
```

which is not the desired result.

The full rules are defined in ["3 Grapheme Cluster Boundaries"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)
in the "Standard Annex #29 UNICODE TEXT SEGMENTATION" in the
Unicode standard.

Comment: Hi Martin. First of all many thanks for the answer. As you said that there are the cases where this won't work, but I tried your code and it's working fine. here is my full string with many flags [""] which has been separated to ["", "", "", "", ""]. One more thing I was trying to solve this from yesterday onwards but couldn't be able to make it. Can you please tell me how you learn those things and which documentation I should prefer?

Comment: I also tried this logic with flags, and it worked fine for a couple different flags.

Comment: @KiranJasvanee: The "problem" has been fixed in Swift 4 (currently beta).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code [example](http://github.com/GabrielMassana/SearchEmojiOnString) or this [pod](http://cocoapods.org/pods/SearchEmojiOnString).

To use it in Swift, import the category into the `YourProject_Bridging_Header`

```
#import "NSString+EMOEmoji.h"
```

Then you can check the range for every emoji in your String:

```
let example: NSString = "‍‍‍" // your string

let ranges: NSArray = example.emo_emojiRanges()  // ranges of the emojis

for value in ranges {

   let range:NSRange = (value as! NSValue).rangeValue

    print(example.substringWithRange(range))
}


// Output: ["‍‍‍", ""]
```

[I created an small example project with the code above.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/GetEmoji)

For further reading, this interesting article from [Instagram](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/118304328152/emojineering-part-2-implementing-hashtag-emoji).