# How to get an emoji at a given index from a Swift String?

Tags: ios, string, swift, unicode, emoji

When accessing a character at a given index in a Swift String (via subscripting), I'm noticing that emojis are not always represented by single characters.

For context, I'm working on an application in which we're getting the initials of a user's name by taking the first character of their first name and the first character of their last name. When a user has an emoji as the first character of either of those, we want to display that as part of their initials.

Examples:

- "Jonny Appleseed" -> "JA"
- "Jonny seed" -> "J"

Older emojis seem to work fine, and be represented by one character:

```
let smiley = " this is a smile"
print(smiley[smiley.startIndex]) // 
let dog = " this is a dog"
print(dog[dog.startIndex])//
```

However some newer emojis (variable skin tone and variable family emojis in iOS 8.3) seem to be represented by multiple characters:

- The variable skin tone emojis (, , , etc.) all seem to be represented by two characters: one for the base emoji (baby, and one for the skin tone modifier).
- The variable family unit emojis (‍‍‍, ‍‍‍, ‍‍‍, etc.) all seem to be represented by two or more characters.

Is there any way to access an emoji at a given index in a String and retrieve the entire emoji as one character? If not, is there any way to easily inspect a Swift Character and determine if it is an emoji or not?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [How to separate emojis entered (through default keyboard) on textfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524322/how-to-separate-emojis-entered-through-default-keyboard-on-textfield) ?

Comment: @MartinR that works perfectly for this. I tested it with flags, and it seems to work as expected. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You can check this pod I created here https://github.com/GabrielMassana/SearchEmojiOnString or here https://cocoapods.org/pods/SearchEmojiOnString. It is a category, the category allows to check if a string has emojis, the number of emojis and the range of the emojis. I really think you can do what you are searching with the range of the emoji in the string. The problem is if you try to check the number of emojis with a skin tone emoji in iOS < 8.3. Then you will have 2 emojis, and not just one.

Comment: with pod 'SearchEmojiOnString', '~> 1.0', `let example: NSString = "skinemojifamily‍‍‍"`
        
        `let ranges: NSArray = example.emo_emojiRanges()` 
    

        `for value in ranges {
            
            let range:NSRange = (value as! NSValue).rangeValue
            
            print(example.substringWithRange(range))
        }` printing: 

‍‍‍