# Convert a String to an array of characters swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, string, swift, character, swift2

I need to convert a string into an array of characters. This work in Swift 1.2 and lower but doesn't since Swift 2.0

```
var myString = "Hello"
Array(myString)  // ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array, which has been updated for Swift 2.

Answer (score 32):

```
var myString = "Hello"
let characters = [Character](myString.characters)  // ["H","e","l","l","o"]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: why didn't i find this a couple of days ago. much more elegant!

Comment: nice. Might as well make it into a computed var: `extension String {
    
    var charValues : [Character] {
        get {
            guard self.isEmpty else {
                return [Character](self.characters)
            }
            return []
        }
    }
    
}`

Answer (score 11):

First, use the `characters` property of `String` struct :

```
let str = "Hello World"
var charView = str.characters
```

You get an `CharacterView` instance. To access to an element of `charView`, you have to use `String.CharacterView.Index`. If you want to convert this to an array of `String`, do this :

```
let str = "Hello World"
var arr = str.characters.map { String($0) }
```

Now, you have an array of type `[String]` :

```
arr[0] // => "H"
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the `characters` property of `String` since it is no longer a `SequenceType`:

```
var myString = "Hello"
let charactersArray = Array(myString.characters)
```