# Swift2 - Split String to individual characters

Tags: string, split, swift2

I am trying to split a string into individual characters.
The string I want to split: `let lastName = "Kocsis"` so that is returns something like: ["K","o","c","s","i","s"]

So far I have tried:

1. `var name = lastName.componentsSeparatedByString("")`
   This returns the original string
2. `name = lastName.characters.split{$0 == ""}.map(String.init)`
   This gives me an error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call. So basically it does't accept "" as an argument.
3. `name = Array(lastName)`
   This does't work in Swift2
4. `name = Array(arrayLiteral: lastName)`
   This doesn't do anything.

How should I do this? Is There a simple solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Swift string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple solution

```
let lastName = "Kocsis"
let name = Array(lastName.characters)
```

The creation of a new array is necessary because `characters` returns `String.CharacterView`, not `[String]`