# "for char in self" has a error says "type string does not conform to protocol sequencetype"

Tags: ios, swift, macos

"for char in self" has a error says "type string does not conform to protocol sequencetype"

I did the exact same thing as the tutorial and the error doesn't show on the tutorial.

Is this error about the version of Swift?

How to fix it?

Thx

```
import UIKit
import Darwin

extension String{
    var asArray:[Character]{
        var result = [Character]()
        for char in self{
            result.append(char)
        }
        return result
    }
}

var str = "a random string"
print(str.asArray)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have any recommend tutorial for latest the version Swift?

Comment: Related: [Convert Swift string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an array of `Character(s)` in Swift 2.2 you can use the following code

```
let text = "Hello World"
let chars = Array(text.characters)
print(chars) // ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```