# Swift 3: What´s the most efficient way to access a Character in a String via Index?

Tags: swift, string, swift3

I´m currently solving some questions from Leetcode, and every time it has something to do with String stuff, I´m getting significantly longer runtimes than with other programming languages.

It must have something to do with the variable memory for Strings that Swift has introduced, therefore you cannot simply say `string[i]` and get the character with a time complexity of O(1), but you have to do something like this:

`string[string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: i)]`

or (even better):

`string.substring(with: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..< string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: i+1))`

Who knows a more efficient way to access Characters via Index in Swift 3? Time complexity of O(1) preferred!

Comment: You cannot access the n'th character of a Swift string in O(1). Often it is better to avoid indexing and *iterate* over the characters instead. Accessing the `.utf16` view seems to be faster.  Saving the characters into an array can be another option. – Have a look at [Slow Swift String Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371929/slow-swift-string-performance) for a similar question (which also happens to be about a Leetcode problem) and possible solutions.

Comment: Iterating over characters is slow because Swift's notion of a `Character` (a Unicode extended grapheme cluster) is **completely** different from most other programming languages notion of a Character, that usually being a single UTF8/16/32 code point. Extended grapheme clusters have varying length, so indexing into an array of them is not a simple `startPointer + count * size` operation as it would be with fixed sized characters

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Iterating (`for c in s.characters {}`) is not too bad. But it gets really slow with  `for i in 0..<s.characters.count { c = s[s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: i)]; ... }` because each index operation is O(i), which makes the loop O(N^2), and that seems to be what OP is doing.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, that approach hurts. Unfortunately, a lot of these code competition questions revolve around repeated random access to a string.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: There are also some SO answers with Swift extension methods for "easy" integer subscripting – instead of saying "don't to it" :)

Comment: Well, I guess a good and simple solution would be to precompute: `var array: [Character] = []
for char in string.characters {
    array.append(char)
}` After that, I can just handle it like in other languages. To be honest, out in the real world, you´re not accessing strings via index on a daily basis. It´s just a vehicle for these programming riddles.

Comment: @MartinR I'm certainly not saying "don't do it", but rather "don't do it via `.characters`", as you said, accessing `.utf16` code points is faster

Comment: @stk You can achieve that same result by just using `Array(string.characters)`

Comment: @stk: That is one of the suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40536964/1187415.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov nice hint, thanks!

Comment: @stk Also, if you must use repeated `append`s, for whatever reason, and you know the number of elements you expect to append, you should call `reserveCapacity()` to prevent multiple array reallocations as its size grows.

Comment: @MartinR Well, kinda. You´re using ArraySlice there, which may be of course even more efficient, but honestly I don´t get all of the code at first glance. `let arr = Array(string.characters); arr[0]` is pretty straightforward, but of course generates more space complexity.

Comment: @stk: I used ArraySlice there because taking "subarrays" (corresponding to substrings of the original string) is faster with ArraySlice than with Array.

Comment: @MartinR Sure, go ahead. I didn´t find the other question, maybe because it is somehow weak-titled.

Comment: @MartinR IIRC `ArraySlice` has the same implementation as `Array`. They're instantiations of the same GYB template

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Perhaps my last comment was misleading. Subscripting an Array with a range returns an ArraySlice (which references the original elements). The code in the linked-to A needs to recursively extract subarrays, and then it is faster to pass ArraySlice's around (which all reference the original elements), instead of converting the result of the subscripting to a "real" Array (which makes a copy).