# What is the bottleneck of the following Swift based XML Parser?

Tags: xml, swift, macos, parsing

I wrote a simple xml parser. But the performance is awful. I cannot figure out what's the problem and where is the bottleneck with my code which is compiling by Swift 3.1 on macOS Sierra.
When I test the code on some XML file (has about 43000 characters) it took about 4.5 mins to parse the file! This is my source code:

```
class Parser {

let ignorableChars : [String] = [" ", "\"", "=", "\r", "\n", "\t"]

var i : Int
var xmlString : String
var stack : [Element]

init(xmlString: String) {
    self.i = 0
    self.xmlString = xmlString
    self.stack = [Element]()
}

func ignoreProlog() -> Void {
    while self.xmlString[self.i] != "<" {
        self.i += 1
    }
    self.i += 1

    if self.xmlString[self.i] == "?" {
        self.i += 1
        while self.xmlString[self.i] == "?" && self.xmlString[self.i + 1] == ">" {
            self.i += 1
        }
        self.i += 2
    }
    else {
        self.i -= 1
    }

}

func ignoreMiscChars() -> Void {
    while self.ignorableChars.contains(self.xmlString[self.i]) {
        self.i += 1
    }
}

func extractType() -> String {
    var elementType : String = ""

    while self.ignorableChars.contains(self.xmlString[self.i]) == false && self.xmlString[self.i] != ">" {
        elementType.append(self.xmlString[self.i])
        self.i += 1
    }
    return elementType
}

func extractKey() -> String {
    var attrKey : String = ""

    while self.ignorableChars.contains(self.xmlString[self.i]) == false && self.xmlString[self.i] != "/" && self.xmlString[self.i] != ">" {
        attrKey.append(self.xmlString[self.i])
        self.i += 1
    }
    return attrKey
}

func extractValue() -> String {
    var attrValue : String = ""

    while self.xmlString[self.i] != "\"" {
        attrValue.append(self.xmlString[self.i])
        self.i += 1
    }
    self.i += 1
    return attrValue
}

func extractElement() -> (Element?, String?) {
    while self.xmlString[self.i] != "<" {
        self.i += 1
    }
    self.i += 1

    if self.xmlString[self.i] == "/" {
        self.i += 1
        let elementType = self.extractType()
        return (nil, elementType)
    }

    self.ignoreMiscChars()
    let elementType = self.extractType()

    var attributes = [String:String]()
    while self.xmlString[self.i] != ">" &&  self.xmlString[self.i] != "/"{
        self.ignoreMiscChars()
        let key = self.extractKey()
        if key == "" {
            break
        }
        self.ignoreMiscChars()
        let value = self.extractValue()
        attributes[key] = value
    }

    let element = Element(type: elementType)
    element.attributes = attributes

    if self.xmlString[self.i] == "/" {
        element.isCompleted = true
    }

    return (element, nil)
}

public func xmlParser() -> Element {
    self.ignoreProlog()
    while stack.isEmpty || stack[0].isCompleted == false {
        let element = extractElement()
        if element.0 == nil {
            if element.1 == stack[0].type {
                stack[0].isCompleted = true
                break
            }
            let lastElement = stack.last
            lastElement?.isCompleted = true
            stack.removeLast()
            stack[stack.endIndex - 1].chidren.append(lastElement!)
        }
        else if element.0?.isCompleted == true {
            stack[stack.endIndex - 1].chidren.append(element.0!)
        }
        else {
            stack.append(element.0!)
        }
    }

    let root = stack.last
    stack.removeAll()
    return root!
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented a custom string `subscript` to be able to index your `xmlString` using an `Int `like that? Otherwise, this code shouldn't even compile on Swift 3.1...

Comment: ... and that subscripting could well be the bottleneck, compare [Slow Swift String Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371929/slow-swift-string-performance). – Did you *profile* your program with Instruments?

Comment: What optimizations do you have turned on, if any? For example, the default optimizations in "release" builds can result in dramatic performance improvements over "debug" builds. But Martin is right, that you should profile the app with Instruments' "time profiler", and that will quickly identify where time is being spent, and you'll be able to quickly diagnose the issue from there.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @PauloMattos solved my problem, and Martin's helped me to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this quick hack to find out if *string subscripting* (ie, `self.xmlString[self.i]`) is your bottleneck:

```
...
var i: Int
let xmlString: [Character]
var stack: [Element]

init(xmlString: String) {
    self.i = 0
    self.xmlString = Array(xmlString.characters)
    self.stack = [Element]()
}
...
```

Freely *indexing* a `String` like that can kill your performance pretty quickly, given all Unicode heavy operations [happening under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536964/819340).

Conversely, converting *once* to a `Character` array, as the above code does, might improve your performance considerably. Indexing an array is a cheap *O(1) operation* (i.e., *constant time*).

Comment: That was an amazing improvement. I can't believe it! thanks a lot.