# Swift string to array of single character strings

Tags: arrays, string, swift4

How can I convert a string into an array of single strings? So `String -> [String]`

If I do `Array(myString)` it results in an array of characters. I tried flatmap (or compactMap in the latest Xcode beta):

```
stringArray = Array(myString).flatMap { $0 as? String }
```

Then I get a warning: "Cast from 'Character' to unrelated type 'String' always fails" and `print(stringArray) results in [].

Is this possible?

Edit: this was already answered in a non-accepted answer in this question: [Convert Swift string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array)

Comment: That answer results in an array of characters, not an array of strings.

Comment: Please read also the second answer.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you use `map` instead of `flatMap`

Comment: Both flatMap and map seem to work, why is the latter preferred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like as follows... Initialize a new string inside the map.

```
let test = "thisIsATest"
let array = test.map( { String($0) })
```

Comment: another simple method is: let anotherArray = Array(test)

Comment: that will result in an Array of Characters, whereas the question was to get Array of Strings.