# How to convert array of integer inside string to array of string?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of `[String : Any]` in which one of the value is of type array of `Int`. Its look something like this:

```
 "file_name" : "anImage.png"
 "type" : "2"
 "data_bytes" : "[-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,2,0,2,0,8,6,-12,120,-4]"
```

Now i am trying to get the value against the key `data_bytes` as integer array but compiler is saying that i can't cast `String` to `Array` or something other. I tried by following codes:

```
dictionary["data_bytes"] as? [Int]      //Failed
dictionary["data_bytes"] as? [NSNumber] //Failed
dictionary["data_bytes"] as? Array    //Failed
dictionary["data_bytes"] as? [Int8]     //Failed
dictionary["data_bytes"] as? String     //Success
```

I also tried looping through all characters in string:

```
 (dictionary["data_bytes"] as? String).flatMap( Int($0) ?? 0 ) //Failed
```

But its giving exception because while looping, there are characters like `[` `]` `,` that is not convertible.

How am I supposed to convert this to array of integers?

Comment: Simple JSON rule: *Everything wrapped in double quotes is `String`*, one string. **Everything** , there is no exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Swift string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921204/convert-swift-string-to-array)

Comment: @TheNeil That's not a duplicate. Look closer.

Comment: Thanks. Flag retracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a json string

```
if let str =  dictionary["data_bytes"] as? String {

     do { 
         let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self,from:Data(str.utf8))
         print(res)
     }
     catch {
         print(error)
     } 

}
```

Comment: @Jamil Please mark the answer accepted if it worked to help others identify the correct answer.

Comment: @Jamil, that string was valid `JSON` array of numbers, so it could be trivially parsed using `JSONDecoder`