# Cannot assign through subscript to Swift String

Tags: swift, string, subscript

I have a class that contains a name, an image, a dashed form of the name, and the length of the name. For example, I could have "dog", an image of a dog,  "---", and name length 3.

I just want to set name and pic for each object and have `dashName` and `nameLength` set automatically.

```
class Answer {
    var name = "name"
    var image: UIImage?
    var dashName = "name"
    var nameLength = 0

    init(){

        var a = 0
        nameLength = name.characters.count

        while a <= nameLength {
            if (name[a] == " ") {dashName[a] = " "}
            else {dashName[a] = "-"}
            a += 1
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the error that says: "cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only" and another error that says: "subscript is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript operator for `String` is get-only, which means you can only read from a string using it, and have to use something else to write to a mutable String.

You can solve this issue, and clean up the code by using a `map` function on `name`

**Swift 4**

```
class Answer {
    var name = "name"
    var image: UIImage?
    var dashName = "name"
    var nameLength = 0

    init()
    {
        nameLength = name.count
        dashName = name.map { $0 == " " ? " " : "-" }.joined()
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
class Answer {
    var name = "name"
    var image: UIImage?
    var dashName = "name"
    var nameLength = 0

    init()
    {
        nameLength = name.characters.count
        dashName = name.characters.map { $0 == " " ? String(" ") : String("-") }.joined()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `String`'s subscript operator is get-only, use `map` method instead, like:

```
class Answer {
    var name = "name"
    var image: UIImage?
    var dashName = "name"
    var nameLength = 0
    
    init(){
        dashName = String(name.map {$0 == " " ? " " : "-"})
    }
}
```

Comment: Spaces should be left alone, any other character should be replaced by a "`-`"

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653964/8740349) before,
Swift's `String` class is what other languages call a `StringBuilder` class, and for performance reasons, Swift does **NOT** provide setting character by index; If you don't care about performance a simple solution could be:

```swift
public static func replace(_ string: String, at index: Int, with value: String) {
    let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
    let end = string.index(start, offsetBy: 1)
    string.replaceSubrange(start..<end, with: value)
}
```

Or as an extension:

```swift
extension String {
    public func charAt(_ index: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)];
    }

    public mutating func setCharAt(_ index: Int, _ new: Character) {
        self.setCharAt(index, String(new))
    }

    public mutating func setCharAt(_ index: Int, _ new: String) {
        let i = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        self.replaceSubrange(i...i, with: new)
    }
}
```

> **Note** how above needs to call `index(...)` method to convert integer to actual-index!? It seems, Swift implements `String` like a linked-list, where `append(...)` is really fast, but even finding the index (without doing anything with it) is a **linear-time** operation (and gets slower based on concatenation count).