# How to swap two characters in String Swift4?

Tags: ios, string, swift4

> **in
>   Swift4, the String is Collections.** **You will no longer use 
>   characters property on a string.**

```
func swapCharacters(input:String,index1:Int,index2:Int)-> String { // logic to swap }

let input = "ABCDEFGH"
```

If I call the function with **(input,3,8)** then the output should be

**Output :** ABC**H**EFG**D**

Note: In Swift4, Strings are collections.

Comment: what have you tried? *Why* swap B and C, because you always want to switch B and C or because they are at index 1 and 2 or because they are in the middle or because they are next to each other?

Comment: @kumar Reddy on what algo are you selecting B & C for swap? What if string goes ABCDFGHRFYUJITR?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace nth character of a string with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789515/how-to-replace-nth-character-of-a-string-with-another)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fairly straightforward since `String` is a collection:

```
func swapCharacters(input: String, index1: Int, index2: Int) -> String {
    var characters = Array(input)
    characters.swapAt(index1, index2)

    return String(characters)
}

let input = "ABCDEFGH"
print(swapCharacters(input: input, index1: 3, index2: 7)) //ABCHEFGD
```

or, to provide a direct array-like operation:

```
extension String {
    mutating func swapAt(_ index1: Int, _ index2: Int) {
        var characters = Array(self)
        characters.swapAt(index1, index2)
        self = String(characters)
    }
}

var input = "ABCDEFGH"
input.swapAt(3, 7)
print(input) //ABCHEFGD
```

Comment: Whats is the time complexity of your solution? I see you are creating new String on each mutation. Is it O(n)?

Comment: @Aamir It's obviously `O(n)` depending on the length of the `String`. If you need lots of similar operations, you should use arrays of characters instead of a `String` because the conversion from `String` to `[Character]` is the slow thing here.

Comment: If this is the case, do you think replacing Sequence at the given range would be a better option? At least it wouldn’t be O(n).

Comment: @Aamir I don't think it would help much. String characters are not the same length - `String` can store them in different ways, and that means that replacing a character can actually mean changing the whole sequence of bytes. With short strings the difference will be probably negligible anyway.

Comment: But it’s worth mentioning that if you are dealing with utf8 sequence then replacing a range might be of benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for String manipulation without converting it to array.
I won't say it's great solution, but does its job.

```
func swapCharacters(input: String, index1: Int, index2: Int) -> String {
var result = input
let index1Start = input.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: index1)
let index1End = input.index(after: index1Start)

let index2Start = input.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: index2)
let index2End = input.index(after: index2Start)

let temp = input[index2Start..<index2End]
result.replaceSubrange(index2Start..<index2End,
                       with: input[index1Start..<index1End])
result.replaceSubrange(index1Start..<index1End, with: temp)

return result
```

}

print(swapCharacters(input: "ABCDEFGH", index1: 3, index2: 7))

prints: ABC**H**EFG**D**

Answer (score -5):

Your question doesn't make sense. Strings in Swift are not indexed by Int. You need to first figure out for yourself what a **Character** really is (an Extended Grapheme Cluster). Then you need to figure out why Int cannot be used as the index for Strings. And then you can come up with a *real* problem. Read up here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: I am solving data structure problems in Swift while doing the permutations for a string i need to swap the elements. So how should I do that without accessing the index?

Comment: "Int cannot be used as the index for Strings"?? For a given Swift string value are there not a countable and ordered set of indexes? That Swift *choose* not to use integers is just that, a *choice* - maybe a good one, maybe not, but there is no *cannot* here surely?