# Deleting the nth occurrence of a word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Json response which comes in html format. I want to remove the ID from the response. There are 3 occurrences of "Optional Coverages" in the string. I want to delete the 3rd occurrence within `<b>` tag using javascript/angularjs.

```
<div class=\"something\">    <a name=\"Optional Coverages\" id=\"Optional Coverages\"></a><b>Optional Coverages</b><br/>         <p align=\"left\">
```

Thanks,
Ab

Comment: plz add a snippet of the response

Comment: The response is like: <div class=\"something\">    <a name=\"Optional Coverages\" id=\"Optional Coverages\"></a><b>Optional Coverages</b><br/>         <p align=\"left\">

Comment: input output in the question plz

Comment: What have you tried so far? You tagged your question `javascript` but I see no JS attempts from your side in resolving your own issue. Please share anything you have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843441/javascript-how-can-i-replace-only-nth-match-in-the-string answer to this question might suffice your case