# How to use regex to format a comma separated map structure

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++, sublimetext2

Using a text editor, without writing JavaScript functions (e.g. can't use this great answer: [Replacing the nth instance of a regex match in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183/replacing-the-nth-instance-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript))

How do I take something like this (a proprietary code structure I have no control over)

```
map(key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3, key4, value4 ...)
```

And convert it to this

```
map(
  key1, value1,
  key2, value2,
  key3, value3,
  key4, value4 
  ...
)
```

One option I found was using this regex to find every 2nd comma  `(([^,]*,){2})`

Then replace with `\1\n\t`

But I would like to improve it:

**1. It doen't handle the first and last lines very well**

```
 map(key1, value1,
    key2, value2,
    key3, value3,
    key4, value4 ...)
```

**2. Only works on a flat structure**

e.g. I can't think of a way to transform this

```
map(key1, value1, key2, map(key3, value3, key4, value4 ...), key5, value5)
```

To this

```
map(
  key1,value1,
  key2,map(
    key3,value3,
    key4,value4 
  ),
  key5,value5    
)
```

Using regex, or is there a way?

Comment: if you tag it with vim, one day you will throw notepad-- away. :)

Comment: Use a scripting language (eg Perl, Python, Ruby, etc) to perform the change. That's what those tools are for. Especially since you can have nested `map` statements...you'll want to write a parser.

Comment: @Kent ok :) funny I didn't think to look for a windows based vim, just downloaded one, will try

Comment: @JackManey yep, I would default to that, but was hoping there is a way to have a shortcut in an editor to do that, I guess the answer is simply write a sublime text 2 python plugin (and I'm sure you could do the same for vim). Just wondered if there is anyway to use regex for this solely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eran, oh you finally tag the question with `vim`, nice! ^_^

vim can format it a bit, I wrote a small function:

**Note that I used `\r` as linebreak, if it doesn't work for you, change into `\n`**

```
function! ExpandMap()
    let s = line('.')
    exec 'silent s/(/(\r/g'
    let e = line('.')
    exec 'silent '.s.','.e.'s/),\=/\r&\r/g'
    let e = line('.')
    exec 'silent '.s.','.e.'s/,[^,]*\zs,\ze/,\r/g'
    let e = line('.')
    exec s.','.e.' normal =='
endfunction
```

You can put it in your `.vimrc` file, if you use that very often. Also you could just give it a try by typing `:so %`

You can create a map for that function call by:

```
`nnoremap <leader>r :call ExpandMap()<cr>`
```

in this way, if you want to reformat your `map` line, just move cursor to that line, and in `Normal` mode type `<leader>r` (default  is \)

This function will change

```
map(k1, v1, k2,  map(k3, v3, k4, v4), k5, v5, k6, map(k7, v7,k8,v8,k9,v9),k10,v10,k11,v11)
```

into

```
map(
        k1, v1,
        k2,  map(
            k3, v3,
            k4, v4
            ),
        k5, v5,
        k6, map(
            k7, v7,
            k8,v8,
            k9,v9
            ),
        k10,v10,
        k11,v11
)
```

Here I show how it works:

- I split the window into two, just show the function
- I created a mapping after the function
- I make two nested maps, also to make the line short, I just used `k#`, `v#`

[image]

Now, when are you gonna uninstall your notepad++? ^_^

Answer (score 1):

A very basic implementation, replacing "Down" in the direction of text.

Find:

```
([^(,)]+,[^(,)]+)
```

Replace:

```
\n\t\1
```

Note that this does not work on `...` (what is that?), and it does not do anything fancy with nesting depth. Keeping track of the nesting depth would require a parser with abilities beyond those of regex. Parsing a programming language is as hard as [parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/697568).

Comment: oh, the ... means "and so on" (e.g. the number of pairs is not known). Ok, makes sense, so Regex is the tokenizer/lexer and I need a parser to make an AST out of it (or something like that?)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with those terms (I just Wiki'd them) but that sounds accurate.