# jquery / JavaScript replace xth occurrence

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a string like this:

`var str = "A    A    A    A    A";`

how do I replace a specific A with something else?

Eg: replace 3rd A to:

`var str = "A    A    00    A    A";`

Of the 1st, 2nd, etc.. ?

Comment: google 'javascript replace nth occurrence', there are so many variants on stackoverflow alone that i don't even know which one to say this is a duplicate of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing the nth instance of a regex match in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183/replacing-the-nth-instance-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I would split the str, replace whatever index, then join back

```js
var str = "A    A    A    A    A";
var sp=str.split('   ');
var ind=2;
sp[ind]='00';
console.log(sp.join('   '));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use regular expression, here is the answer:

```
newValue = str.replace(/(([^A]*A){2}[^A]*)A/g, '$100');
```

Notes:
{2} is the number of the occurrence we want to replace.

$100 here we specify which is the new string we want to place after the $1